# if coroutine is run end after loadscene

Tags: unity-game-engine

before load oher scene,i have many task to run ,for example save some date to sql and so on,i run the task at coroutine.As you know when call SceneManager.LoadScene,the ondestory  is call,so my questions are:

1. if load other scene until coroutine run finish,or coroutine is break through my task is not finish.
2. startcoroutine should before SceneManager.LoadScene,or put at the ondestroy
   3.if i use SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync not  SceneManager.LoadScene,if  coroutine will break

Comment: It is impossible to understand your question. It would make sense for you to rephrase everything in your question then end your actual question with a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [Object.DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) in the Awake method of your MonoBehaviour where your coroutine task runs, like described on Unity documentation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

This code will allow your coroutine ends even if another level was loaded.